# Comparing two string to see if there is a pattern match

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays one outputting

```
$a = ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => b [3] => a )
```

and the other outputting

```
$b = ( [0] => dog [1] => cat [2] => cat [3] => dog )
```

how can i compare the pattern in both arrays.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: Compare and then what? What you expect to get from comparing?

Comment: Give us more details you want to compare what exactly? What do you expect as output?

Comment: i want to compare them so if $a = a b a b and $b stayed the same the pattern would be different  . i.e $a = abba and $b = dog , cat ,cat, dog should return true where as $a = abba and $b = dog , cat , cat, fish would return false

Comment: is this a static array? I mean you want specifically to make it work for this array size?

Comment: @Andy Did this solve Your problem? How does this look at the pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$a = array( 0 => 'a' ,1 => 'b', 2 => 'b', 3 => 'a' );

$b = array( 0 => 'dog', 1 => 'cat' ,2 => 'cat' ,3 => 'dog' );
$flagA=0;
$flagB=0;

$pattern=array();
$i=0;
foreach ($a as $array){

    if($array=='a'){
        $pattern[$i]=1;
        $flagA++;
    }
    else{
        $pattern[$i]=0;
        $flagB++;
    }
    $i++;
}

print_r($pattern);


$flagarrayB=0;
$flagarrayC=0;

$testingPatern=array();
$i=0;
foreach ($b as $arrayB){

    if($arrayB=='dog'){
        $testingPatern[$i]=1;
        $flagarrayB++;
    }
    else{
        $testingPatern[$i]=0;
        $flagarrayC++;
    }
    $i++;
}

print_r($testingPatern);

if(serialize($pattern) == serialize($testingPatern)){
    echo "Patern is the same";
}
else{
    echo "Patern is wrong";
}

if($flagA==$flagarrayB && $flagB==$flagarrayC){
    echo "TRUE";
}
else
{
    echo "FALSE";
}
```

If you try to change a value in array $b you will see that the output will change

- I modified my code to work with the "pattern" not only with the appearance of elements. My previous code if in array $b you switched places with cat-dog it would return true. In this one it will return That the pattern is wrong. I keep also my previous code in case you want to use it that way.

Comment: @Andy Did this solve Your problem? How does this look at the pattern?

Comment: yep this works , although i changed it so instead of quote the 'a' i changed it to $a[0] and the same for 'dog' thanks for your help :)

Comment: Ok good, although I dont understand how this verifies that the pattern is the same(x,yy,x). Isn't this just comparing occurrences of two values?

Comment: Modified my existing code. @msfoster was right about the pattern issue. Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have these three arrays:

```
$a = array(0 => 'a',1 => 'b',2 => 'a',3 => 'b');
$b = array(0 => 'a',1 => 'b',2 => 'a',3 => 'b');
$c = array(0 => 'dog',1 => 'cat',2 => 'cat',3 => 'dog');
```

You compare their values by using `==` operator

```
$a == $b; //return TRUE
$a == $c; //return FALSE

if($a == $b){//will return TRUE
  //$a has the same values as $b
}
else{
  //$a is different than $b
}
```